# Success is not something that just happens (by accident or by chance)

Tags: word-choice

Which word is more appropriate? And why?

Success is not something that just happens by *_*.
 A. accident
 B. chance

Comment: You're missing a word between "something" and "just", and since you do it twice I assume it's a "real" mistake rather than a typo. If you're writing for British English speakers, insert "which"; if writing for American English speakers, insert "that".

Comment: @ peter: you are right. It's a mistake. I corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say either. Both *chance* and *accident* describe random events. It's true that *accident* also can carry the additional meaning of misfortune, but that is not its only meaning. Good things can happen purely by accident as well.

> **accident** .. 2 an event that happens by chance or that is without apparent or deliberate cause : the pregnancy was an accident | *it is no accident that my tale features a tragic romance*.
>   • the working of fortune; chance : *my faith is an accident of birth, not a matter of principled commitment* | *he came to Harvard largely through accident*

All right, now consider this: You can use either *accident* or *chance* in your statement, but that will not make it true. People can become successful through an accident of birth; in fact, starting life rich is one way to be rich later on.

Comment: in the most oriental religious thinking, a birth with special condition, bad or good, is not an accident, but the result of the person's previous life.

Answer (score 1):

I would say B: Chance.

Accident has a negative connotation of an unintentional, unfortunate incident happening, whereas chance would refer to luck.

Comment: I found below definition and example sentences using dictionary.cambridge.org
--------------
by accident
without intending to, or without being intended

I deleted the file by accident.
I found her letter by accident as I was looking through my files
--------------
The first example may be suggesting negative connotation, but second is neutral in my sense. Though I am not a native speaker and I am not quite sure about my English sense. Further explanation is appreciated .

Comment: This is not true. *Accident* can be a synonym of *chance* (see my answer here) and you can have bad luck as well as good.